# Font-weight !important in element identity is being overridden

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got an animated section [at the very bottom of this page](https://cv.devops.unlimitedgrowth.io/start-ups/#bottom) that works as expected when you click on the "Next Category" DIV container, except that the text's `font-weight`  does not change...

I understand that the style of child element always override the parent style even with the use of `!important`, but my JQuery directly gives this text a class that has `font-weight: 400 !important`, and other elements in the same site with 400 font weight display this lighter Google font just fine -it is a font that by default has different weights after all- so I do not understand...

This is the jQuery

```
    $('.clickable').on('click', function() {
        $('.clickable').attr('id', 'ScaleDown');
        $('.dot').css('opacity', '0');
        $('#next').addClass('lighter')
        $('.category').addClass('ScaleUp');
});
```

This is the CSS

```
.clickable {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 1s;
}

#ScaleDown {
    transform: scale(0.33);
    transition: all 1s;
}

.lighter {
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}

.category {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 1s;
}

.ScaleUp {
     transform: scale(1);
     opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: if you inspect the h3 contained in #next you will see you have another style that specifically sets the font-weight to 600. You need to specifically target the h3 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule has to select the `h3` tag

```
.lighter h3 {
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}
```

because of this existing rule

```
body.elementor-page-300 h3, body.elementor-page-300 .elementor-widget-heading h3.elementor-heading-title, body.elementor-page-300 h3 a, body.elementor-page-300 .elementor-widget-heading h3.elementor-heading-title a {
    font-family: "PT Serif", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

which styles the `h3` tag already.

Comment: thank you for the additional explanation it's very appreciated to understand better the issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `<h3>` font-weight, since it is declared specifically for this tag in the stylesheet.

If you change this

```css
.lighter {
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
```

to this

```css
.lighter h3.elementor-heading-title {
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @GoldenPony! If my answer solved your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark below the up/down voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

There's a font-weight attribute set on the h3 tags.

If you target the h3 tag in the .lighter class, you can override the applied font-weight.

Try this:

```
.lighter h3 {
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
```